# SQL Joins and Output format

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Can any one help me with the below sql?

```
**Table A**

Id  Seq   First_Name    Last_Name
1   1     John          Walter 
1   2     Michael       Jordan
1   3     Sally         May
```

I want my output to look something like below where for a given Id, for each sequence number, I want to get first name and last name of the other sequence numbers.

Example Output

```
Id  Seq   Name
1   1     Michael Jordan | Sally May 
1   2     John Walter | Sally May
1   3     John Walter | Michael Jordan
```

Any help with the SQL?

Comment: Are there always exactly three sequence-ids for a given id?

Comment: @Rene - no, the table can have any number of sequences!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `collect()` aggregate function.

Here's a link to it's [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions031.htm).

For your case, this would be:

```
create or replace type names_t as table of varchar2(50);
/

create or replace function join_names(names names_t) 
                  return   varchar2
as
  ret varchar2(4000);
begin
  for i in 1 .. names.count loop

      if i > 1 then
         ret := ret || ',';
      end if;
      ret := ret || names(i);

  end loop;

  return ret;
end join_names;
/


create table tq84_table (
  id         number,
  seq        number,
  first_name varchar2(20),
  last_name  varchar2(20)
);

insert into tq84_table values (1, 1, 'John'   ,  'Walter');
insert into tq84_table values (1, 2, 'Michael',  'Jordan');
insert into tq84_table values (1, 3, 'Sally'  ,  'May'   );


select
  t1.id,
  t1.seq,
  join_names(
           cast(collect(t2.first_name || ' ' || t2.last_name order by t2.seq)
                as names_t)
  )
from
  tq84_table t1,
  tq84_table t2
where
  t1.id   =  t2.id and
  t1.seq !=  t2.seq
group by t1.id, t1.seq
```

If you're using Oracle 11R2 or higher, you can also use
[LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions089.htm), which is a lot simpler (without the necessity of
creating a *type* or *function*):

The query then becomes

```
select listagg(t2.first_name || ' ' || t2.last_name, ',') 
       within group (order by t2.seq)
         over (partition by id) as names
  from .... same as above ...
```

Comment: To be precise: LISTAGG was introduced 11.2. it is not available in 11.1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: that's right. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Will work not only for 3 columns.This is in general.

```
 DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + First_Name +' '+Last_Name FROM A
WHERE Seq !=2 and Id IS NOT NULL
select Id,Seq,@Names from A where Seq = 2
print @Names
```

You need to pass the Seq value so that you can get the records.
Thanks,
Prema

Comment: The `@variables` syntax is unknown to Oracle.

Comment: @ René Nyffenegger - I told it in SQl

Comment: Oracle knows about SQl, too, but it still won't work there, and this not only for the `@variables` syntax, but also for the `coalesce()` thingy you mentioned. So, it's not *in general*, at least not, if the OP specifically asked for *PL/SQL* and *Oracle*. You know, just because Microsoft likes to call their product *SQL Server* doesn't mean they have sort of a SQL standared. -1.

Comment: @ René Nyffenegger - I dint say Oracle is not SQL.I mean to say i said it in sql server.In that it will support know